# Using Autohotkey for Emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard, cygwin, autohotkey

I am using emacs in Cygwin and have used Autohotkey to re-map the lefthand 'Alt' key and the lefthand 'Windows' key to be (left)Ctrl and (left)Alt respectively.

This means that an emacs sequence like <kbd>Ctrl-x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> is done with my left thumb pressing on the key labelled 'Alt' to produce the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Ok.

All seems okay except that I cannot get <kbd>M-SPC</kbd> to work, so my question is to ask for help on that.

Here is the Autohotkey script I am using (by the way it is only for theoretical completeness that I re-map the lefthand Ctrl key to be the lefthand Windows button -- I have never actually pressed it when using emacs):

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class mintty
LWin::LAlt
LAlt::LCtrl
LCtrl::LWin
```

To be clear, when I say 'all is ok' I mean that within emacs I use the 'describe key sequence' feature (<kbd>C-h</kbd> then <kbd>k</kbd>) and then try out the key combination I want. For example, all of these show the emacs documentation for the sequence I expected:

- Key labelled 'Alt' + <kbd>g</kbd> reports emacs documentation for `C-g`. **Good**.
- Key labelled 'Alt' + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> reports the documentation for `C-@`, which emacs says is also mapped to `C-SPC`, so that seems okay. **Good**.
- Key labelled 'MSWin Symbol' + <kbd>x</kbd> reports documentation for `M-x`. **Good**.
- Key labelled 'MSWin Symbol' + key labelled 'Alt'+ <kbd>k</kbd> reports documentation for `C-M-k`. **Good**.

But:

- Key labelled 'MSWin Symbol' + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> shows me the 'right-click' menu for the cygwin window rather than taking me to the documentation for `M-SPC`. **Bad**.
- By the way, I can get to the documentation for `M-SPC` by instead doing <kbd>ESC</kbd> followed by <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

Let me add another point which has come up in the process of reacting to comments on this question:

- Key labelled 'MSWin Symbol' + key labelled 'Alt'+ <kbd>SPACE</kbd> takes me to the documentation for `C-@`, so I suspect it is being understood by emacs as <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> rather than as <kbd>C-M-SPC</kbd> as I thought my Autohotkey script would map it to. **Bad**.

Any ideas on why Autohotkey won't do the `M-SPC` as I would expect, or why <kbd>C-M-SPC</kbd> is understood by emacs as a `C-SPC` (I suspect)?

Thanks

Comment: Funnily enough, in another SO question that I am involved in (see the first comment in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15884328/1243435), Thomas mentions that C-M-SPC can be problematic in some terminals and explains that for him it does exactly what I am seeing here -- it produces a right-click menu for the terminal itself.

Comment: that's quite a weird remapping...  Most people who do remap CTRL remap it to CAPS-LOCK.  Also quite some expensive keyboards come with CTRL in place of CAPS-LOCK (which is where CTRL was on older keyboards btw), like the Happy Hacking Pro 2 for example.  Note that if you're touch typing you'll find CTRL-x quite hard to do correctly, no matter where you put CTRL, so you can use Emacs and *ctl-x-map* to remap all the "C-x ..." shortcuts to something else (I'm using C-, instead of C-x).

Comment: On my MacBook at home the CMD key sits next to the space-bar, ie. exactly where the Alt key is on my PC keyboard. On the MacBook the CMD key is often used in circumstances where Ctrl would be used on a PC. I got to like it. I did try the pinkie remapping of using the PC's CAPS-LOCK as the Ctrl but that hurts! My poor little finger was aching! Rather, with the PC's Alt as Ctrl you just tuck your (stronger) thumb under the arch of your fingers and bingo! there is Ctrl. Nicer, I think. On this one I would claim that Apple got the layout right (let's not discuss their placement of '#').

Comment: You're complaining about "Key labelled 'Alt' + SPACE" being misunderstood; but you've made it clear that the Windows logo key is your Meta, so you should amend this to say "Key labelled 'MSWin Symbol' + SPACE". Unless I've really misunderstood something (not hard to do when you're talking about shifting so many keys around!)

Comment: @echristoperson You are right. I am about to correct that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here are answers to your problem:

[Issues remaping ctrl to alt and alt to ctrl for Emacs](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/95740-issues-remapping-ctrl-to-alt-and-alt-to-ctrl-for-emacs/)

[And a discussion of why that happens](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/95806-question-about-internal-realisation-of-alt-remapping/)

Plus to the script that can be found following first link you can add this code to work will all possible keyboard layouts.

```
#IfWinNotActive, ahk_group HaveEmacsHotkeys
#InputLevel 1
; Aditionally remaps Window keys and AppsKey
*RWin::
    SetKeyDelay, -1
    Send, {Blind}{Alt DownTemp}
    return 
*RWin up::
    SetKeyDelay, -1
    Send, {Blind}{Alt Up}
    return

*LWin::
    SetKeyDelay, -1
    Send, {Blind}{Alt DownTemp}
    return 
*LWin up::
    SetKeyDelay, -1
    Send, {Blind}{Alt Up}
    return

*AppsKey::
    SetKeyDelay, -1
    Send, {Blind}{Alt DownTemp}
    return 
*AppsKey up::
    SetKeyDelay, -1
    Send, {Blind}{Alt Up}
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 1):

Alt+Space is a standard Windows shortcut for showing the window menu, which you can also get by left-clicking on the window icon or right-clicking on the titlebar.

You can disable that shortcut on the Keys page of the Cygwin terminal's options (together with the Alt+Enter shortcut for fullscreen, for which Alt+F11 can be used instead).

Comment: Understood, and have un-set it in the terminal options. However, within emacs my 'test' of using C-h k to describe a key sequence tells me that C-M-SPC is interpreted as C-SPC (this was what Thomas actually explained in the comment I mentioned above).

Comment: You didn't say anything about C-M-SPC in your original question. FWIW, it works fine for me (not using AutoHotKey): "C-M-@ runs the command mark-sexp, which is an interactive compiled Lisp function. It is bound to C-M-@, C-M-SPC."

Comment: My apologies, I had got a couple of sentences muddled in my original question. I am now updating it to correct those and to include mention of the problem with C-M-SPC only being seen as C-SPC by emacs.

Comment: Regarding C-M-SPC, does it work without the AHK script, pressing the actual Ctrl+Alt+SPC keys?

Comment: Good point! Yes it does work: I turn off AHK and my `C-h k` test in emacs correctly takes me to the documentation for `C-M-@` (bound to `C-M-SPC` as you will know) when I press Ctrl+Alt+SPACE. Thank you for the good question! That pretty-much proves that I *do* have a problem with my AHK script as I suspected (coz I am an AHK novice).